# Class implements interface with property that implements "sub" interface

Tags: c#, class, interface, extends

I've an issue by implementing this model.
I've classes A and B, that implements and interface IX. IX has 3 properties, one of this is also an interface IY. I need in A and B to have a class that implements IY.
I tried

```cs
public interface IX {
   public string x1 {get; set;}
   public IY x2 {get; set;}
}

public interface IY {
}

public class Y: IY {}

public class A: IX {
   public string x1 {get; set;}
   public Y x2 {get; set;}
}
```

But if i try to define this model i get "cannot implement because it does not have the match return type".
I also tried generic to solve the issue:

```cs
public interface IX<TY> where TY:IY {
   public string x1 {get; set;}
   public TY x2 {get; set;}
}

public interface IY {
}

public class Y: IY {}

public class A: IX<Y> {
   public const string TYPE = "a";
   public string x1 {get; set;}
   public Y x2 {get; set;}
}
```

but now i'm not able to deserialize it by using json converter. It seems that not recognize the right Jsonconvert so i get error by deserializing. I've this JsonConverter

```cs
public class InterfaceJsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T>
    {
        private string _fieldJsonType { get; set; }

        //it is used to match the type in json to c# class 
        private const string STATIC_FIELD_NAME = "TYPE";

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("serialization is not implemented");
        }

        public override T ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, T existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
            string typeFromJson = jo[_fieldJsonType].Value<string>().ToLower();
            T target;

            // Get type with reflection assegnable for interface T
            var types =
            (from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
             where typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(t) && (!t.IsInterface && !t.IsAbstract)
             select t);

            Type selectedType = null;
            foreach (var t in types)
            {
                var propInfo = t.GetField(STATIC_FIELD_NAME, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
                if (propInfo == null)
                    throw new Exception($"In type {(t.GetType().Name)} is not defined {STATIC_FIELD_NAME} field");

                var typeFromClass = propInfo.GetValue(null) as string;

                if (typeFromClass?.Equals(typeFromJson, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ?? false)
                {
                    selectedType = t;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (selectedType == null)
                throw new ArgumentException($"no types find for type {typeFromJson}");

            target = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(selectedType);

            using (JsonReader jsonReader = jo.CreateReader())
            {
                serializer.Populate(jsonReader, target);
                return target;
            }
        }


        public InterfaceJsonConverter()
        {
            _fieldJsonType = "type";
        }

        public InterfaceJsonConverter(string fieldJsonType)
        {
            _fieldJsonType = fieldJsonType;
        }
    }
```

and i use TYPE property to choose from class A or B based on a value. I create jsonconverter by doing

```cs
new InterfaceJsonConverter<IX<Y>>()
```

Is there a way to fix my class without using generic?
Thanks to all

Comment: Shouldn't the implementation in the `A` class look like this? `public IY x2 { get; set; }`

Comment: If i use IY instead of Y, i need to implement a converter that deserialize IY in Y. But in A x2 Is always instance of Y. I can use the constructor to make It Y, but im not sure Is a good practice

Comment: Interface `IY` doesn't define any public properties and therefore an object instance of `IY` can't be serialized, but if your `Y` class has public properties defined then an instance of it can be. I would suggest that you define the public properties of `Y` in your interface `IY`